# Python index error string

Tags: python, rsa, sage

I seem to be getting the following error -

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-582a33edccfc> in <module>()
 10         string = alphabet[i] + string
 11     return string
 ---> 12 ptext=number2string(int(dec))
 13 print ptext

 <ipython-input-46-582a33edccfc> in number2string(M)
  8         i = M % Integer(100)
  9         M = (M-i)/Integer(100)
 ---> 10         string = alphabet[i] + string
 11     return string
 12 ptext=number2string(int(dec))

 IndexError: string index out of range
```

For the following code -

```
n = 80590779575522264848081505402281132333075026055511
d = 5096598073523319979793354769252907316734417084656927459986239265286821982150579957763648301138598311
cipher= 60411283179665957400593484939411104457866145531782
dec = pow(cipher,d,n)
print dec
alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,.?!:;-\'\"'
def string2number(string):
   M=0
   for i in range(len(string)):
       M = 100*M + alphabet.index(string[i])
   return M
def number2string(M):
    string=''
    while M > 0:
        i = M % 100
        M = (M-i)/100
        string = alphabet[i] + string
    return string
ptext=number2string(int(dec))
print ptext
```

I am trying to perform RSA encryption and decryption. The code worked fine before. This is just an excerpt i isolated. I understand there are other questions like this but i just couldnt get figure this out with those solutions.

Comment: can you also paste value of n ?

Comment: There is some more missing code. What's alphabet?

Comment: what is `alphabet` ? Definitely the length of `alphabet` string is smaller than the value of `i` at the time of the exception. <-- That's all we can tell you based on the code you shared

Comment: I have added the missing code. I am new to python. Pardon the mistakes.

Comment: M % 100 gives a number between 0 and 99. alphabet has only 72 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you are doing % 100 it is fetching last 2 digits which is showing error so replace `i = M % 100` & `M = (M-i)/100` with  `i = M % 10` & `M = (M-i)/10`

**output:**

5351520757559142628218193819530718324607905389694
5351520757559142628218193819530718324607905389694